# Google Maps добавить в инфоблок фото из базы данных

Tags: google-maps-api, photo

из базы данных через XML беру данные для маркеров и инфоблока, в поле photo указан путь к картинке images/nophoto.png пытаюсь вставить фото в инфоблок маркера, не получается. Пробовал по разному что-то никак не разберусь...

```
// читаю хмл файлик
        downloadUrl('http://map.loc/dbtoxml.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
                var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
                var markers = markerElem.getAttribute('markers');
                var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
                var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
                var photo = markerElem.getAttribute('photo');
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                    parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));
                // формирование информационного бокса для маркеров
                var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
                var strong = document.createElement('strong');
                strong.textContent = name
                infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
                infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                var text = document.createElement('text');
                text.textContent = address
                infowincontent.appendChild(text);
                infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                text.textContent = type
                infowincontent.appendChild(text);
                infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                // добавляю фото в инфоблок маркера
                var image = 'https://map.loc/'+
                    photo;
                infowincontent.appendChild(image);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

никто не ответил, но и на том спасибо... в интернете ответа не нашел, пришлось крутить самому. Выкладываю тут для тех кто ищет ответ на этот вопрос.
Так в инфоблоке появляется привязанная к маркеру картинка вытащенная из базы данных через XML

```
// добавляю фото в инфоблок маркера
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = (""+photo+"");
            infowincontent.appendChild(img);
```